# PyCharm - Local Processes window not showing names of programs

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I'm attempting to attach to and debug a python script being run through the command line. When searching for instructions on how to do so, I see that most screenshots provided show the PID followed by the name of the program, as seen below.

[image: Documentation screenshot]

However, my run window only shows the PIDs with no mention of the program's name:

[image: My Attach Prompt]

This is frustrating because I am unable to look through the PID's of running programs while the window is open. Once I click on the Task Manager window, the prompt disappears. Furthermore, even when I take a screenshot of the prompt, none of the PIDs match any of my running services.

I have to debug by attaching to the command line because the arguments that I'm trying to pass aren't accepted properly when setting up a Debug Configuration. This is making it basically impossible to debug this program efficiently. Can anyone tell me if there's a setting where I can have the Attach to Process prompt show program names?

Comment: When I attach to processes I do indeed get a window that looks like the first picture. A couple questions: What OS are you on? Are you expecting to see those 6 python processes in your window or do you not know what those are? Have you run ps  to find what the PID name of your program is and then see if that is in your list?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. I'm not expecting to see 6 processes at all - I only have one running that I'm aware of. I actually forgot to try tasklist. It looks like my process is in that list.

However, this doesn't change that fact that I would still like to get the list of programs to appear next to the PIDs. As mentioned, clicking over to cmd causes the attach prompt to close, so it's very inconvenient to try to compare. The functionality clearly exists, I just don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Hmm.. seems very strange. Problem I am having is that I cannot recreate the error so I can't debug on my own. So I guess lets just try some stuff. If you create another project and run a simple program say `while(True): print("Hello World!")` and try to connect to that through pycharm does it have the same issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to powershell, you can get the PID using `Get-Process`

Comment: This doesn't tell me how to get process names in PyCharm, though. I can find PIDs just fine, but when I focus something that isn't PyCharm, the prompt to attach to a process vanishes.

Comment: @Inagnikai is getting the name *before* you open the prompt not an option..?

Comment: It is an option, and it is the option I am forced to use at the moment to attach to my processes. However, I am specifically looking for information on how to get the process names to show up within PyCharm. I know it is an option, I just don't know how to enable it. It seems as if you're reading this question as "how do I attach to processes", rather than "how do I get names to show up next to PIDs to more easily attach to processes on the fly".

Comment: @Inagnikai actually, you're correct, I did read it that way. In my defense, this is close to being off topic for SO (there is one bullet point in the guidelines saying questions about tools are allowed; I didn't think they were until I read it for this comment). Apologies! What version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: No apology necessary. I have PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.1